# How do I stop my account name appearing in Office application title bars?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, office365, username, title-bar

I have an Office 365 Subscription with Office 2016 installed. All of my Office Apps including Word, Excel, Access and PowerPoint include my name in the application title bar, near the top right corner, adjacent to the "Ribbon Display Options", "Minimize", "Restore/Maxmize" and Close buttons.

I'd like to take some screenshots **without** including my name in every screenshot. How can I prevent my name from appearing in the title bar?

Answer (score 1):

This has been an unresolved issue with Microsoft for some time now. The only ways to do this, are to either sign out, or change the "FriendlyName" keys in the registry. Signing out is the better option, as the "FriendlyName" keys are restored whenever Office 365 pushes an update through.

I've had it change back while live streaming, so I just stay signed out now, unless I have to use OneDrive, Outlook, or am actually at work.

Edit 8/23/2020: At least for me anyway, signing out now deactivate my license, making everything "Read Only" and changing the registry rarely works for more than a few minutes, if at all. M$ has become quite aggressive with user account control these days...